# I'm building a browser based in C#, when I press E while typing in the URL the browser tries to navigate to the address

Tags: c#

I'm new to this, ask me if you need anything more. This is what I've written so far.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateToPage();
    }


    private void NavigateToPage()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }



    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if( e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.Enter);
        {
            NavigateToPage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please specify whats your question

Comment: When I press the E button on my keyboard, it tries to load the URL thats in the textbox. I'm asking how can I fix that

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the `NavigateToPage` method to see what is triggering it? There really isn't enough information here for us to help you.

Comment: `ConsoleKey.Enter` is an enumeration. Converting that to a char is probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong event (maybe this is a reason why pressing <kbd>E</kbd> cause navigation) to check for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use `KeyDown` instead:

```
void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        NavigateToPage();
}
```

Comment: You can get the Enter key with the `KeyPress` event unless you have intercepted it with something like `AcceptButton`.